# Can't enter If statement when looping through Arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, for-loop, foreach

New to Arrays and after finally getting my String array all sorted out I cannot seem to find the error that is keeping me from entering an if statement. Due to this I can't set value for my Array of integers. Code Below:

```
Dim Task() As String

Dim stringchain As String

Dim TaskNum As Integer

Set SearchRange = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

Task() = Split(stringchain, "|")

TaskNum = UBound(Task) - LBound(Task) - 1 'equals 32

'Setting intial TotalSample array to zero

Dim TotalSamples() As Integer

ReDim TotalSamples(0 To TaskNum)

Dim zzz As Integer

For zzz = 0 To zzz <= TaskNum

TotalSamples(zzz) = 0

Next zzz

'Counting Total samples for each task and setting value in excel

For Each cel In SearchRange

'MsgBox InStr(1, cel, Task(iii)) > 0

Dim iii As Integer

For iii = 0 To iii <= TaskNum

MsgBox InStr(1, cel, Task(iii))

'Never seems to enter if statement on next line, even when tested true

If InStr(1, cel, Task(iii)) > 0 Then

        TotalSamples(iii) = TotalSamples(iii) + cel.Offset(0, 1).Value

        Range("K4").Offset(iii, 0).Value = TotalSamples(iii)

        MsgBox "here"

        End If

Next iii

Next cel

'Output for any TotalSamples() is zero.
```

Comment: The variable `stringchain` is never initialized.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the OP is new to VBA so before comments  on the code there are 4 things we must  discuss.  These four things are very important for a Novice VBA'er as they reduce the pain of writing VBA code by a significant amount.

1. Always, Always, Always put option explicit at the start of each module/class/form.
2. Use F1.  Putting the cursor on a Keyword in the VBA IDE and pressing F1 will bring up the MS help page for that keyword.  If you get a line highlighted in yellow it pays to do this for each keyword in that yellow line.
3. Always compile your code before trying to run it.  In the VBA Ide use Debug.Project Compile  to catch logic and syntax errors that have not been caught by option explicit.
4. Install the fantastic and free VBA addin [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/).  Among its many talents Rubberduck will do a more strict analysis of your code and will educate you about assumptions you didn't know you have made.

Now onto Code.

Generally in VBA, Integer is converted to Long internally so there is no advantage to declaring variables as Integer rather than long.

The for loop is For  =  to

So

```
For zzz = 0 To zzz <= TaskNum
```

should be written

```
For zzz = 0 To Tasknum
```

The original version considers 'zzz<= Tasknum' as a Boolean expression, the result of which will be coerced to -1 or 0.  Thus the OP code is essentially saying

```
For zzz = 0 to -1
```

and consequently the For loops will never execute.

Try to use meaningful variable names and particularly avoid names that essentially duplicate keywords.  e.g. myCell is preferable to cel.

Always qualify Range, Cell keywords with the Workbook.Worksheet to which they belong.  Without such qualification you are referring to the active sheet which can change without warning and consequently produce strange errors.